# delphi XE multi-unit namespace question

Tags: delphi, namespaces, delphi-xe

I am reading RAD Studio Documentaion in Delphi XE.
here a some texts.

> [ Delphi Reference -> Delphi Language Guide -> Programs and Units  -> Using Namespaces -> Searching Namespaces -> Multi-unit Namespaces ]
>
> **Multi-unit Namespaces**
>
> Multiple units can belong to the same namespace, if the unit declarations refer to the same namespace. 
>       For example, one can create two files, unit1.pas and unit2.pas, with the following unit declarations:

```
// in file 'unit1.pas' 
unit MyCompany.ProjectX.ProgramY.Unit1 

// in file 'unit2.pas' 
unit MyCompany.ProjectX.ProgramY.Unit2
```

> In this example, the namespace MyCompany.ProjectX.ProgramY logically contains all of the interface symbols from unit1.pas and unit2.pas.
>
> Symbol names in a namespace must be unique, across all units in the namespace.
>       In the example above, it is an error for Unit1 and Unit2 to both define a global interface symbol named mySymbol

I tested this. 
code below .

```
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
program Project1; 

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE} 

uses 
  SysUtils, 
  Lib.A in 'Lib.A.pas', 
  Lib.B in 'Lib.B.pas'; 

begin 
  WriteLn ( TestValue ) ; 
  ReadLn ; 
end. 
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
unit Lib.A; 

interface 
  const TestValue : Integer = 10 ; 
implementation 

end. 
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
unit Lib.B; 

interface 
  const TestValue : Integer = 10 ; 
implementation 

end.
```

This is not error. Why? I don't understand.

Comment: What happens if you *only* `uses SysUtils, Lib` in `Project1` and do `TestValue: Integer = 20` in `Lib.B` and then do `WriteLn(TestValue)` in `Project1`?

Comment: I suppose Codegear had some irregular plans on extending .Net concept of namespaces on Delphi for Win32 which have never been implemented. Where are just no multi-unit namespaces in Delphi, and it is hard to say what the above documentation is about.

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not match the documentation. Documentation explicitly states that file name of 'unit MyCompany.ProjectX.ProgramY.Unit1' is unit1.pas, not MyCompany.ProjectX.ProgramY.Unit1.

I do not believe, however, that this feature is implemented at all. If I change your code to store first unit in file a.pas and second unit in file b.pas, units don't compile at all and the error is

```
[DCC Error] A.pas(1): E1038 Unit identifier 'Lib.A' does not match file name
```

(Which is exactly as I was expecting to see.)

In your case there's no conflict because you can always use a full name of 'conflicting' global - Lib.A.TestValue and Lib.B.TestValue.

Comment: I also got the same error, but I am using Delphi 2009. Maybe this is new to XE (or 2010).

Comment: Just verifying: you are using Delphi *XE*? Asking because usually the documentation is lagging behind the features and not the other way around? From your answer to Andreas, I see you did. Interesting.

Comment: When was this 'multi-unit namespace' feature introduced? It seems not to be there in Delphi 2009, so it has to be 2010 or XE. (Even though in 2009 there are units like `Generics.Collections` etc.)

Comment: Maybe you need some compiler switch to use namespaces? I seem to recall there is a setting somewhere in the compiler options related to namespaces.

Comment: @Marjan: I have no idea if you are talking to the OP, to gabr, or to me! :)

Comment: @Andreas: maybe to all of you :-) The D2009 namespace options only deal with the default name space and being able to shorten uses clauses by specifying one or more dotted prefixes. ie use DB instead of CodeGear.Vcl.DB, but that seems strange because by default the list is empty and I have never had to write CodeGear.Vcl.DB...

Comment: Just tested: if you list "Generics" in the projects "standard namespace", you can write "uses Collections, Defaults", which doesn't compile otherwise. Although I currently don't get the big benefit in here.

Comment: It will compile if you explicitly define 'Lib' as the default namespace in the project options.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi.NET (before Prism): unit name = namespace. That's the way they used it in that time - and in dotNET an unit was really an namespace (inclusive appear as such in generated IL).

In native Delphi, I don't see the difference (if that exists at all).