# Undocumented intrinsic routines

Tags: delphi, documentation, intrinsics

Delphi has this list: [Delphi Intrinsic Routines](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines)
But that list is incomplete.

What are the 7 undocumented intrinsic functions, since when and what is their purpose?

Comment: It's not too broad, there are only 7 undocumented intrinsics.

Comment: since you've already answered that... I'll hit skip and leave this to someone with more clue of Delphi to decide.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I know of the following undocumented intrinsic functions.

Delphi 2007: [here](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.rtl/201003/1003152761.html) and [Hallvard's blog](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2007/08/highlander2-beta-generics-in-delphi-for.html):

**Default**

```
function Default(T: Typeidentifier): value of T;
```

Returns the zero representation of type identifier `T`.

The following intrinsics introduced in XE7 are explained [in the XE7 beta blog](http://xe7beta1.blogspot.com/) and by [Stefan Glienke](http://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2014/10/new-language-feature-in-xe7.html)

**IsManagedType**

```
function IsManagedType(T: TypeIdentifier): Boolean;
```

True if `T` is a `interface`, `string` or `dynamic array`, or a record containing such. A class containing a managed type will return false.

In XE6 and older you have to use [`System.Rtti.IsManaged(TypeInfo(T))`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Rtti.IsManaged).

**HasWeakRef**

```
function HasWeakRef(T: TypeIdentifier): Boolean;
```

True if `T` has been annotated as `[weak]`. The compiler keeps a list of `[weak]` references. You cannot use `move` and other tricks with these types, because that will prevent the weak-list from getting updated.

In XE6 and older you have to use [`System.TypInfo.HasWeakRef(TypeInfo(T))`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.TypInfo.HasWeakRef).

**GetTypeKind**

```
function GetTypeKind(T: TypeIdentifier): TTypeKind;
```

Does the same thing as `PTypeInfo(System.TypeInfo(T))^.Kind;`, however because it is a compiler intrinsic the function is resolved at compiletime and conditional code that evaluates to false will be stripped by the compiler.

**IsConstValue**

```
function IsConstValue(const Value): Boolean;
```

True if Value is a constant, false if not.
This helps the compiler to eliminate dead code because the function is evaluated at compile time.
This is only useful in inline functions, where it allows for shorter generated code.

**TypeInfo**

```
function TypeInfo(T: typeindentifier): PTypeInfo;
```

This function is not undocumented as such, but what **is** undocumented is that it is an intrinsic function since XE7.
That means that the snippet `if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(byte) then ...` does not generate any code if T is not a byte and the test will be resolved at compiletime.
However the compile-time resolution only works inside generic routines and only when doing a `if (TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(sometype)` test.
The test `if TypeInfo(byte) = TypeInfo(smallint) then` does not get eliminated even though it always evaluates to false.
Nor does other use of `TypeInfo(T)`.

**ReturnAddress**

The following are used with the `raise exception at returnaddress` construct.

```
function ReturnAddress(Expression): pointer;          //Delphi ?
function AddressOfReturnAddress(Expression): pointer; //Delphi ?
```

And as far as I know you can't call them directly from user code.

Example of `IsConstValue`

> ```
> type
>    TFlavor = (Tasty, Nasty);
>    TIntegerHelper = record helper for integer
>      function GetSomething(Flavor: TFlavor): TPoint; inline;
>    private
>      function GetTastyPoint: TPoint;
>      function GetNastyPoint: TPoint;
>    end;
>  
>  function TIntegerHelper.GetSomething(Flavor: TFlavor): TPoint;
>  begin
>    if IsConstValue(Flavor) then begin
>      if Flavor = Tasty then Result:= Self.GetTastyPoint
>      else Result:= Self.GetNastyPoint;
>    end else begin
>      Assert(1=0, 'This function can only be called with constant parameters');
>    end;
>  end; 
>
> procedure Test;
> var
>   pt: TPoint;
> begin
>   pt:= 100000.GetSomething(Tasty);
> ```
>
> This call will get translated to GetTastyPoint and the `if/then` sequence will be eliminated by the linker.