# Can I do my coursework with a newer Delphi version than my school uses?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10-seattle

We started at school learning Pascal using Delphi 7 (which is old little bit) and when I checked Wikipedia and Delphi website it seems like there is other versions and the last one which was released on August 31 is Delphi 10 Seattle . So my question is should I download the same thing as my school (Delphi 7) or it's normal if I use Delphi 10 ? can I import projects from Delphi 7 to Delphi 10 and vice-versa ?

Comment: You can import projects from Delphi 7 into 10 without problem, but it won't work importing 10 into 7.

Comment: Read a [List of Delphi language features and version in which they were introduced/deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8460037/576719).

Answer (score 5):

I would not recommend using Delphi 10 Seattle if your course using Delphi 7. You'll run the risk that when you submit your assignments, they won't work on your instructor's environment. When I was an instructor, I made it clear to my students that they would be grading on how their programs behaved in the school's computer-lab environment. They were welcome to install development tools on their personal computers and work on their homework that way, but it was merely a convenience; I still expected them to test their code on the lab computers prior to turning in their work.

I encourage you to check with your instructor that there are similar expectations for your class.

Delphi 7 is no longer sold in any official capacity. (It hasn't been for over a decade.) If your course uses Delphi 7, then your instructor or institution should provide some means of accessing it outside of your class time. Maybe they offer the software in your school bookstore, or maybe you can access it in a computer lab.

You can import old projects into the new Delphi version, but your instructor will not be able to open your Delphi 10 Seattle project in Delphi 7.

Using any other version, you risk submitting assignments that don't work in your instructor's environment. The "works on my machine" excuse is not worth much, especially after repeated attempts.

If you plan to do more with Delphi beyond this one class, then you will benefit from using a modern version, but for the purposes of this class, you should stick with the same version all the course materials use.