# Are constant record's unlisted elements initialized with default values in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, initialization, constants, record

Let's suppose these declarations:

```
type
  TMyRec = record
    Name    : String;
    Age     : Integer;
    Married : Boolean;
  end;

  TMyRecArray = Array[0..3] of TMyRec;

const
  RecArray: TMyRecArray = ((Name: 'John' ; Age: 25; Married: False),
                           (Name: 'Wendy'; Age: 32                ),
                           (Name: 'Nick' ;          Married: True ),
                           (               Age: 19; Married: False));
```

Are the unlisted record elements in the last three array rows auto-initialized with default values? Or do (can) they contain random data?

[Embarcadero's docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Declared_Constants#Record_Constants) doesn't say anything official on this.

Comment: The answer is yes, but sadly this is undocumented: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Declared_Constants#Record_Constants

Comment: No errors. When trying it seems that the values are being initialized, but it doesn't prove anything, I could only be lucky. Also local variables often contain what can seem to be a default value (0 for numbers, False for booleans), but we know for sure they're not initialized at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I read that page before asking ;)

Comment: Would have been nice to include a link to it in the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan done

Comment: FWIW, the link @David gave has a big error. It says "and the tag field, if there is one, must have a value specified; if the record has a variant part, only the variant selected by the tag field can be assigned values. " That's nonsense, AFAIK. There doesn't even have to be a tag field, and if there is one, its value is irrelevant. But you can't define two separate variant parts in the same const.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your record array constant declaration with default values can be declared as:

```
const
  RecArray: TMyRecArray = ((),
                           (),
                           (),
                           ());
```

So yes, omitting record fields in the constant declaration will produce default values.

---

Unfortunately, this behavior is undocumented. You will have to use the debugger to verify.
The Delphi predecessor, Turbo Pascal, worked almost the same way. You had to include values for all fields up to the last non-default field.

Comment: See also [How to set default value to record in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46764196/576719)

Comment: Thank you LU RD. Is this documented somewhere? (not in the record constants official docwiki, unfortunately).

Comment: No, it is not documented

Comment: So we can say this is the actual behaviour only by reverse engineering of the compiled code?

Comment: That's correct. You need to look at the data that is written into the executable to represent the constant. Inspect it under the debugger.

Comment: In other words: it has been that way for a long time, and it is very unlikely to change. But the fact it is (still) undocumented means that it *could* change, one day. To be sure, simply fully declare the constant.