# Does Delphi 7 support the inline keyword?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
procedure display;inline;
begin
  showmessage('sakthi');
end;

procedure TFrmInline.BtnDisplayClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  display;
end;
```

In this program if i compile it shows the error that "declaration expected but inline found".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delphi 7 has no support for the `inline` keyword and will not inline functions.

The inline keyword was added in Delphi 2005: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460108/

Comment: @sakthivel Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answers your question and AFAIK it does then please accept it. [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)